# How to only push newly change from parent branch

Tags: git, github, branch

Let's say in git, I have **branch_A**, then I created a **branch_B** depending on branch_A by

```
(branch_A) git checkout -b branch_B
```

Then commit something in branch_B.

When I want to create a pull request to GitHub, how can I **only push newly change** that happens in **branch_B**?

Comment: If you create a pull request from `branch_B` into `branch_A`, then you'll only see the commit in `branch_B` as part of the change set. Otherwise if you're doing it from `branch_B` back to your master branch, you'll get any changes in `branch_A` too (there's no way to exclude them).

Comment: Branch B contains everything in the repo at the time it was created. That includes all changes on branch A. If you only want to add branch B change's back in, you'll need to cherry pick the individual commits.